# Can't allocate memory for swap in vram

Tags: nvidia, gpu, nouveau

I'm trying to make a swap in VRAM like in [Arch.Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Swap_on_video_RAM). My video card Nvidia GTX 275 has 896 MiB onboard:

```
[    9.818641] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: NVIDIA GT200 (0a0300b1)
[    9.946633] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: bios: version 62.00.59.00.02
[    9.967125] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fb: 896 MiB GDDR3
[   10.207255] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 896 MiB
[   10.207260] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
[   10.207264] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: DRM: TMDS table version 2.0
[   10.207267] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
```

However, only 256MiB+16MiB+32MiB are mapped into the memory address space:

```
lspci -vnn -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT200b [GeForce GTX 275] [10de:05e6] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
        Memory at f8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at 9f00 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
<...>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

also:

```
cat /proc/iomem
00000000-00000fff : Reserved
00001000-0009f7ff : System RAM
0009f800-0009ffff : Reserved
00000000-00000000 : PCI Bus 0000:00
000a0000-000dffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  000c0000-000cdbff : Video ROM
000e0000-000effff : pnp 00:05
000f0000-000fffff : Reserved
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-dfedffff : System RAM
dfee0000-dfee0fff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
dfee1000-dfeeffff : ACPI Tables
dfef0000-dfefffff : Reserved
  dfef0000-dfefffff : pnp 00:05
dff00000-febfffff : PCI Bus 0000:00

>>>  e0000000-efffffff : PCI Bus 0000:03
>>>    e0000000-efffffff : 0000:03:00.0   -----> 256 MiB

  f0000000-f3ffffff : PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-3f]
    f0000000-f3ffffff : Reserved
      f0000000-f3ffffff : pnp 00:04
  f4000000-f41fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
  f4200000-f43fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
  f4400000-f45fffff : PCI Bus 0000:05
  f4600000-f47fffff : PCI Bus 0000:06

>>>  f6000000-f9ffffff : PCI Bus 0000:03
>>>    f6000000-f7ffffff : 0000:03:00.0   -----> 32 MiB
>>>    f8000000-f8ffffff : 0000:03:00.0   -----> 16 MiB

  fb600000-fb6fffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
    fb600000-fb60ffff : 0000:01:00.0
    fb6ff000-fb6ff7ff : 0000:01:00.0
      fb6ff000-fb6ff7ff : ahci
  fb700000-fb7fffff : PCI Bus 0000:09
    fb700000-fb70ffff : 0000:09:00.0
    fb7f8000-fb7fbfff : 0000:09:06.0
    fb7fe000-fb7fe7ff : 0000:09:06.0
      fb7fe000-fb7fe7ff : firewire_ohci
    fb7ff000-fb7ff0ff : 0000:09:00.0
      fb7ff000-fb7ff0ff : 8139too
  fb800000-fb8fffff : PCI Bus 0000:02
    fb8fe000-fb8fffff : 0000:02:00.0
      fb8fe000-fb8fffff : xhci-hcd
  fb900000-fb9fffff : PCI Bus 0000:08
    fb9f8000-fb9fbfff : 0000:08:00.0
    fb9ff000-fb9fffff : 0000:08:00.0
      fb9ff000-fb9fffff : r8169
  fba00000-fbafffff : PCI Bus 0000:08
    fba00000-fba1ffff : 0000:08:00.0
  fbb00000-fbbfffff : PCI Bus 0000:07
    fbbf8000-fbbfbfff : 0000:07:00.0
    fbbff000-fbbfffff : 0000:07:00.0
      fbbff000-fbbfffff : r8169
  fbc00000-fbcfffff : PCI Bus 0000:07
    fbc00000-fbc1ffff : 0000:07:00.0
  fbd00000-fbdfffff : PCI Bus 0000:06
    fbdfe000-fbdfffff : 0000:06:00.0
      fbdfe000-fbdfffff : ahci
  fbe00000-fbefffff : PCI Bus 0000:05
    fbefe000-fbefffff : 0000:05:00.0
      fbefe000-fbefffff : ahci
  fbff8000-fbffbfff : 0000:00:1b.0
    fbff8000-fbffbfff : ICH HD audio
  fbffc000-fbffc0ff : 0000:00:1f.3
  fbffd000-fbffd3ff : 0000:00:1d.7
    fbffd000-fbffd3ff : ehci_hcd
  fbffe000-fbffe3ff : 0000:00:1a.7
    fbffe000-fbffe3ff : ehci_hcd
  fbfff000-fbffffff : 0000:00:13.0
fec00000-ffffffff : Reserved
  fec00000-fec003ff : IOAPIC 0
  fed00000-fed003ff : HPET 0
    fed00000-fed003ff : PNP0103:00
  fed10000-fed1dfff : pnp 00:05
  fed1f410-fed1f414 : iTCO_wdt.1.auto
  fed20000-fed8ffff : pnp 00:05
  fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC
    fee00000-fee00fff : pnp 00:05
  ffb00000-ffb7ffff : pnp 00:05
  ffb80000-ffbfffff : INT0800:00
  fff00000-ffffffff : pnp 00:05
100000000-c1fffffff : System RAM
  be9000000-bea404d47 : Kernel code
  bea600000-beac58fff : Kernel rodata
  beae00000-beb15c2bf : Kernel data
  beb9cf000-bebdfffff : Kernel bss
```

So, as i understand, `nouveau` uses only 304MiB (256+16+32) of VRAM and other 592 are wasted. Is it possible to map the tail 592MiB into the address space to grab them for a swap?